# Crankshaft sensor and pulley

Tags: oil, oil-pan

I installed a new crankshaft position sensor on my 99 Buick Park Avenue and replaced the harmonic balancer.[image]As I was starting in I heard loud noises and oil leaking from the oil pan so I removed the oil pan and saw huge pieces of metal or aluminum in it,what is it

Comment: Bits left from a catastrophic failure.

Comment: Remove the pieces, clean them, and lay them out on a clean surface. Now put the pieces together like a jigsaw puzzle. Post a second picture if you can.